# How to align horizontal icon and text in Material UI

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am a newbie in Material UI, now my icon and text are not aligned:

[image: not align]

My desired results:

[image]

My code is:

```
<div style={{
    display: 'inline-flex',
    VerticalAlign: 'text-bottom',
    BoxSizing: 'inherit',
    textAlign: 'center',
    AlignItems: 'center'
}}>
    <LinkIcon className={classes.linkIcon}  />
    revolve
</div>
```

I tried grid and row, but not work. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 113):

This works perfectly!

```
<div style={{
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
}}>
    <LinkIcon />
    <span>revolve</span>
</div>
```

Material-UI has introduced components that handles this scenario better than using a style:|

```
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';

<Stack alignItems="center" direction="row" gap={2}>
  <LinkIcon />
  <Typography variant="body1">Revolve</Typography>
</Stack>
```

Comment: I used the style but applied them to a single `Typography` so I did not need the `p` element. Works a charm with `v4.0.2`.

Comment: In newer versions of Material its preferred to use the 'Box' or 'Stack' components for flex.

Answer (score 60):

This can be easily achieved in **MUI v5** by using a [`Stack`](https://mui.com/components/stack/#direction) and set `alignItems` prop to `center`:

```js
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import AddCircleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AddCircle';
```

```
<Stack direction="row" alignItems="center" gap={1}>
  <AddCircleIcon />
  <Typography variant="body1">text</Typography>
</Stack>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 50):

You need to use Grid.
Something like that should works:

```
<Grid container direction="row" alignItems="center">
  <Grid item>
    <LinkIcon className={classes.linkIcon} />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item>
    revolve
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Perfect, if the text gets longer than the row by default the grid starts wrapping which means the text will be below the icon, to prevent this you can add `wrap="nowrap"`

Comment:  Feels more like the 'MUI' way, using their components. BTW, `direction="row"` should not be needed. Pretty sure it's the default.

Comment: FYI the alignItems should go into the child Grid item accompanied with display="flex"

Answer (score 33):

Try the below code. You can use `variant` as per your requirement.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  wrapIcon: {
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    display: 'inline-flex'
   }
}));

<Typography variant="subtitle1" className={classes.wrapIcon}>
    <LinkIcon className={classes.linkIcon}  /> revolve
</Typography>
```

Comment: hello @chetan-gawai I'm not really sure to understand where you use your `useStyles` variable defined at first...

Comment: @maxxyme usually the example is `const classes = useStyles();` in a function. You can see where `classes` is then being used in the render/return.

Comment: hi, how can I add horizontal spacing between the icon and the text?

Comment: hi.. finally i you have resolved my issue

Comment: `'inline-flex'` helped keep everything centered. Thank you! The top comment of just `'flex'` wasn't working for me.

Answer (score 22):

alternative simple solution

```
<Grid container direction="row" alignItems="center">
     <SearchIcon /> example
</Grid>
```

Comment: I'm confused why this works, as the [Material UI](https://v4.mui.com/components/grid/) examples always have a `<Grid item` right under a `<Grid container`, but here you only used `<Grid container`. My case is if I add `<Grid container><Grid item>`, the `alignItems="center"` doesn't work, icon still not vertically aligned, but with this solution it's finally working. I also find `<Grid container item` work as well. Since Material UI mentions children of container are items, I think it's canonical to have both `container` and `item`.

Comment: I think that's why they have introduced Stack in V5

Answer (score 7):

styles

```
const styles = theme => ({
    icon: {
        position: "relative",
        top: theme.spacing.unit,
        width: theme.typography.display1.fontSize,
        height: theme.typography.display1.fontSize
    }
});
```

JSX

```
<Typography variant="display1">
    <Icon className={this.props.classes.icon}/>Your&nbsp;Text
</Typography>
```

you could replace `display1` with `display3` or another [typography variant](https://material-ui.com/style/typography/#component) in all 3 places to choose your text size. The `&nbsp;` ensures that your text doesn't break  between words when it wraps.

For me this can render to look like this

[image]

with `display3` and a few other styles added for color.

Comment: hello @nxtman123 I'm not really sure to understand where you use your `styles` variable defined at first...

Comment: @maxxyme that variable goes into `withStyles` HOC see https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api

Comment: Interesting answer, nowadays you would write: `icon: {
    position: "relative",
    top: theme.spacing(0.5),
    width: theme.typography.body1.fontSize,
    height: theme.typography.body1.fontSize
  }`

Comment: @EricBurel, I haven't worked closely with Material UI for a little while now, so feel free to edit this answer to reflect the changes Material UI has had in recent years. I understand they have a new Typography system? My "typography variant" link appears to be outdated.

Answer (score 5):

Having `ListItemIcon` and `ListItemText` wrapped inside a `ListItem` will keep it in one line and prevent breaking:

```
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
    
<ListItem >
  <ListItemIcon><AccessAlarmIcon color="secondary" /></ListItemIcon>
  <ListItemText>Updated 1 hour ago</ListItemText>
</ListItem>
```

Demo image:

[image: Demo image]

Comment: Can you please add a little more context with answer

Comment: Please, just place a link to the image you were trying to attach and explain why `ListItem` solves the problem.

Comment: @Sabareesh, I can see you are brand new to Stack Overflow, so Welcome to the community.  
When answering questions, it's helpful to explain why your answer works.  I'm not sure how the `AccessAlarmIcon` is magically vertically aligned, so please explain why this works.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use Material UI's [Flexbox component](https://material-ui.com/system/flexbox/).

For example:

```
// ...
import { Box } from '@material-ui/core';
// ...

<Box alignItems="center" display="flex">
 <Box>
    <LinkIcon className={classes.linkIcon}  />
 </Box>
 <Box>
    revolve
 </Box>
</Box>
```

The `alignItems: center` attribute will vertically align the inner items.

This will add some additional markup. However, if you look at the component's API there's a lot of additional flexibility. Such as 
 for example a method to [use margin or padding](https://material-ui.com/system/spacing/) that's consistent with the rest of your Material UI implementation. Also it's really easy to align the items differently if the use-case should occur.

Answer (score 3):

You can import these on top

```
import { Grid, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import LinkIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Link";
```

You can use

```
<Grid style={{ display: "flex" }}>
    <LinkIcon />
    <Typography>Revolve</Typography>
</Grid>
```

Sample Sandbox Example [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-icon-align-ozm3g?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to vertical align text and icon within MUI's Typography without using `variant`, you can simply add a display setting to Typography as follows:

```
<Typography display="flex">
    Welcome!
    <Icon />
</Typography>
```

This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen all the solutions. But here is the simplest I believe :-):

```
<Typography><LinkIcon sx={{verticalAlign:"middle"}}/> RESOLVE</Typography>
```

It also works with inline image when you want the image align with the text.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, this is what I did.

```
import LinkIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Link';
import styled from 'styled-components';
...
const Resolve = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  vertical-align: middle,
`;

<Resolve>
  <LinkIcon style={{ marginRight: '5px' }} />
  <p>resolve</p>
</Resolve>
```

If you aren't happy with mUI default link icon you can always DIY:

```
{/* this is the same chained icon used in the own material-ui, 
idk why this ins't avaiable yet */}

function CustomLinkIcon(props) {
  return (
    <SvgIcon {...props}>
      <path d="M4 9h1v1H4c-1.5 0-3-1.69-3-3.5S2.55 3 4 3h4c1.45 0 3 1.69 3 3.5 0 1.41-.91 2.72-2 3.25V8.59c.58-.45 1-1.27 1-2.09C10 5.22 8.98 4 8 4H4c-.98 0-2 1.22-2 2.5S3 9 4 9zm9-3h-1v1h1c1 0 2 1.22 2 2.5S13.98 12 13 12H9c-.98 0-2-1.22-2-2.5 0-.83.42-1.64 1-2.09V6.25c-1.09.53-2 1.84-2 3.25C6 11.31 7.55 13 9 13h4c1.45 0 3-1.69 3-3.5S14.5 6 13 6z" />
    </SvgIcon>
  );
}
...
<Resolve>
  <CustomLinkIcon 
     {/* adjust margin top if needed */}
     style={{ marginRight: '3px', marginTop: '3px' }} {
  />
  <p>resolve</p>
</Resolve>
```

Answer (score 0):

the best option is to use it like that :

```
  import {Box, Typography} from '@material-ui/core'
  import LinkIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LinkIcon';

   ........

   <Box display='flex' alignItems='center'>
       <LinkIcon className={classes.linkIcon}  />
       <Typography variant='h5'>
          resolve
       </Typography>
    </Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this solution the icon will inherit your typography, it prevents having to re-write the style when changin

```
<Typography component={Stack} direction="row" alignItems="center" color="secondary">
     <EditIcon fontSize="inherit" sx={{ marginRight: 1 }} />
     Edit
</Typography>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use Typography to make align horizontal spacing with icon

```
const styles = theme => ({
    icon: {
        fontSize: '1rem',
        position: 'relative',
        right: theme.spacing(0.5),
        top: theme.spacing(0.5),
    },
});


<Typography><CheckCircleIcon className={className={this.props.classes.icon}}/>Home</Typography>
```