# Material ui / typography and button on the same line

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am struggling to align a button and a `<Typography>` component on the same line:

Here is what I have so far:

```
<Grid item lg={12} md={12} sm={12} xs={12} className={classes.register}>
    <Typography noWrap className={classes.typoText} variant="subtitle2">
        text1
    </Typography>

    <ButtonBase className={classes.labelForgot} disableFocusRipple="false" disableRipple="false" centerRipple="false">
        <Typography noWrap className={classes.labelForgot} variant="subtitle2">
            text2
        </Typography>
    </ButtonBase>
</Grid>
```

My styles:

```
labelForgot: {
    color: 'rgba(20, 176, 12,0.9)',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    paddingLeft: 2,
    '&:hover': {
        color: 'rgb(57, 232, 48)',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    }
},
root: {
    backgroundSize: 'cover', 
    backgroundPosition: 'center center',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    minHeight: '100vh',
    justifyContent:'center', 
    overflow: 'hidden',
},
gridMain: {
    margin: '0 auto',
    maxWidth: 300,
},
```

Basically I have a `<div>` that allows a height of ´100%`.

For the container I use css grid main.

[Here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guZGS.png)

Answer (score 3):

[how to align horizontal icon and text in material ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51940157/how-to-align-horizontal-icon-and-text-in-material-ui)

Check this page. I was stuck on the same problem... The suggested solution is wrapping the items with a div...

```
<div style={{
          display: 'flex',
          alignItems: 'center'
}}>
   <Typography noWrap className={classes.typoText} variant="subtitle2">
       text1
   </Typography>

   <ButtonBase className={classes.labelForgot} disableFocusRipple="false" 
      disableRipple="false" centerRipple="false">
      <Typography noWrap className={classes.labelForgot} variant="subtitle2">
         text2
      </Typography>
   </ButtonBase>
</div>
```

I tried to do it with Grids as well from Material UI but was having trouble with a  header and  buttons